# Element-wise multiplication in 2D vectors in C++11

Tags: c++11, vector

I am trying to do element-wise multiplication (.*) between two 2D vectors in C++11 using the code below but I am getting the errors as **Error  C2664   'int std::multiplies::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector>' to 'const int &'** I could not figure out what the actual problem is?

The code I used is as follows

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator> 

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> Route = { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } };
    std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> Spectrum = { { 2,2 },{ 3,3 } };

    std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> score;

    //and do element-wise multiplication of Spectrum and Route i.e. Spectrum .* Route
    std::transform(Spectrum.begin() + 1, Spectrum.end(), Route.begin() + 1, std::back_inserter(score), std::multiplies<int32_t>());

    std::vector< std::vector<int32_t> >::iterator row;
    std::vector<int32_t>::iterator col;
    for (row = score.begin(); row != score.end(); row++) {
        for (col = row->begin() + 1; col != row->end(); col++) {
            std::cout << *col << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to multiply two vectors using `std::multiplies<std::int32_t>`.

Comment: I see the problem now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `Route` and `Spectrum` vectors are instances of `std::vector<int32_t>`. Your transform calls iterate over the mentioned vectors. Instead of a vector, `std::multiplies<int32_t>` expects the arguments to be integers. The error message tells you that there is no way to convert from a vector into an integer.

You could instead iterate over the "top" vectors, and transform each subvector into a subvector of the result "top" vector.